# Text running outside of its box in IE/Opera

Tags: html, css, joomla, html-table

Page: http://www.visitherefordshire.net/news

In Internet Explorer 7 and Opera 9.6, the text is running outside the box. It appears to be due to the tables being 100% width: if I set a pixel width (e.g. 700px) then they fit.

As far as I can see all the 'outer' divs are not wider than the visible box, so why does the 100% width on the table stretch it out so far?

P.S. horrible code, I know; that's Joomla for you. We'll be trying to make it better in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue now. One of the articles had a massive line of spaces in it, causing the table to stretch. It's now fixed. Kinda stupid really!

Answer (score 0):

Just put in your joomla_classes.css (at the end) the following piece of CSS

```
table.contentpaneopen p{
width: 99%;
}
```

Now it should all look fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but this didn't work, the text still runs outside the box.

Comment: No problem. At the time when I posted the answer, with that content on your page worked for me, both in Firefox, IE 6 and IE 7 :)